# How do I get a reference to a cordova plugin?

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins

I am trying to use the cordova-app-preferences plugin.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    alert("doc ready");

    function ok (value) {
        alert("prefs.fetch value: "+value);
    }
    function fail (error) {
        alert("prefs.fetch error: "+error);
    }

    var prefs;

    try {
        prefs = plugins.appPreferences;
    }
    catch (e) {
        alert("can't find plugins.appPreferences");
    }

    prefs.fetch( ok, fail, "mode");

});
```

This fails (catch). When I step using Safari debugger, plugins is undefined. I am running this on my iPhone XS `cordova run ios --device`, cordova version is 8.0.0.

The redacted version of my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >

<head>

  <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
  <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/login.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

So the question is: what am I missing to get a reference to plugins.appPreferences?

UPDATE:
The problem seems specific to this plugin. To replicate,

```
cordova create plugin-test com.mydomain.ptest PLUG
cd plugin-test
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-app-preferences --save
cordova platform add ios
cordova run ios --device
```

(fails, need to specify code signer in xcode.)

`cordova run ios --device`

This time it builds and runs. If I open Safari debug window, cordova.plugins is null.

Now, if I add another plugin (eg. `phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner`) and run it again, cordova.plugins exists, but only contains `barcodescanner`.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is strange, but I discovered that this particular plugin registers itself at runtime using `windows.plugins` while the others that I've looked at use `cordova.plugins`.

Comment: This is all over the place. You'll find plugins also using `window.device` and `window.navigator`. There is no standard in place for this.